# How to update database using the form value & calculation in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

*Currently using sqlite that comes with Django.*

In a `CreateView` of creating a `project` I want to search for `tools` that are in the `tools` database. Upon selecting one, it will display information in a row within the `CreateView`. Upon submitting my `project` I want to `-1` from the `quantity` of that `tool` in the `tools` database.

In reference to my title I am just looking to subtract the value of in the  quantity input from the `tools` database and how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use FBV(Function Based Views) instead of CBV(Class Base Views) since it is much easier to understand and simpler to do things such as this.